# It is possible to pass output parameter in attribute using C# and ASP.NET MVC4?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a question about model validation attributes.

I have an attribute class which validate a field (I validate files).  I need that results of validation from field to be passed to next field, to avoid to do validate again the files, by a variable.

I mean:

```
public sealed class FileValidationAttribute: RequiredAttribute
{
     private bool _validateProtocol;

     public bool ValidateProtocol { get { return _validateProtocol; } }

     public override isValid(object value) {
          if(base.isValid(value)) {
             HttpPostedFileBase[] files = value as HttpPostedFileBase[];

             // do some verification here
             _validateProtocol = true;             
          }

          return false;
     }
}
```

and in my model

```
public sealed class MyModelValidation
{
     [FileValidation]
     public HttpPostedFileBase[] Files { get; set; }

     public bool isValidateProtocol {
        get {
            // I don't want to validate again files here because I did this in above field
            // here I want to get the result from `FileValidation.ValidateProtocol`
        }
     }
}
```

I don't want to do `ValidateProtocol` from `FileValidationAttribute` as static member.

Answer (score 0):

You could have the validation method store the results in a property within the same object (via reflection).  There are a couple of ways I can think of to approach it:

- tag a property with an attribute to indicate the results should be stored there
- create an interface and store the result in the property indicated by interface